# Image Hover Generator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

Let's say I have the following HTML code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Lab 6 - Task 1 </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="imagechanger.js"></script>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    img { width: 300px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <h1> Fernandel Faces </h1>
<img src="face1.png" id="faces">

  <p> Ask a question! </P>
  <p> Move Mouse Over Fernandel for a Response </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have 4 files named `face1.png`, `face2.png`, `face3.png` and `face4.png`, how would I write my Javascript so that when my mouse hovers over the initial image every time, it randomly changes to one of the 4 images?

**ANSWER**:

```
window.onload=function(){

var images = ["face1.png", "face2.png", "face3.png", "face4.png"];

document.getElementById("faces").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    event.target.setAttribute("src", random);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JavaScript:

```
var images = ["face1.png", "face2.png", "face3.png", "face4.png"];

document.getElementById("faces").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    event.target.setAttribute("src", random);
});
```

Comment: where would I put this JS into? my JS file or create a separate script tag in html doc

Comment: For test purposes, place it in a `<script>` tag at the ***bottom*** of your HTML file.

Comment: how would I do it on my JS file, do I have to create a function and then do it?

Comment: No, you could just replace your JS file with the code above and it'll work perfectly. If you have something else in your JS file, could you please post that file?

Comment: so I tried posting it in my JS file without defining a function and nothing changes, as for JS file there is nothing inside. In my JS file I just pasted 

`var images = ["face1.png", "face2.png", "face3.png", "face4.png"];

  document.getElementById("faces").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  event.target.setAttribute("src", random);
});`

Comment: no errors im using atom, it just has the image loaded and doesnt change

Comment: Not in Atom - open the HTML file, Inspect it (ctrl/cmd - shift - i) and see if there are any errors in the Console. Do you know what I mean by Console?

Comment: @ahlie94 Well I can see in the other question you asked (which this one is a duplicate of, by the way) that you have the file path `Images/face1.png` and so on. Try changing this.

Comment: so I just checked on HTML on console log it shows its changed and it displayed this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at task1.js:3`

Comment: ok cool so what I did was I added in the windows.onload function with the code so the website loads up and then executes the JS and it works, thanks